# Problems installing SimpleCV

Tags: python, macos, opencv, osx-lion

I'm having trouble finding out how to install SimpleCV. I followed a YouTube video and I installed it (on OSX Lion with Python 2.6) and everything went fine. Now when I run SimpleCV.command from the application folder I get the following:

```
$ /Applications/SimpleCV/SimpleCV.command
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/SimpleCV/SimpleCV.command", line 2, in <module>
from SimpleCV import *
ImportError: No module named SimpleCV
```

Comment: Was it this video? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kum_pqHePlc

Answer (score 2):

That import error means that the SimpleCV module didn't make it into your Python path.  If you installed with the superpack, this means something probably went wrong with the post-install script hook.

If re-installing the superpack does not work, take a look at http://simplecv.org/doc/installation.html#mac-os-x-10-6-and-above and run the commands in a terminal.